# How to use [(ngModel)] in ngFor with dynamic Name (Key)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-template

I have angular form that are generated by NgFor on two different div. i want to make form fields unique.
[both fields are not working individually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtwfC.png)

```
<div *ngFor="let configField of configFields; let i = index"><mat-form-field fxFlex fxFlex.lt-md="calc(50% - 16px)" >
    <input matInput placeholder="Url" name="url_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="headerFields.url" >
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field fxFlex fxFlex.lt-md="calc(50% - 16px)" >
  <input matInput placeholder="Method" name="type_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="headerFields.type">
 </mat-form-field></div>
```

> i want to add flag on field name for uniquely identified in  (headerFields)Array.. like name="type_{{i}}" type_1 ,type_2

Answer (score 0):

On initialization or assignment of configFields, you can initialize or assign to the headerFields an array of length equal to the one as configFields, with url and type set as empty. Something like the following:

```js
const configFields = [1,2,3];
const headerFields = Array.from(configFields, (el) => ({ url: '', type: ''})) // Set to empty string or null as desired]
```

Comment: yes but i am using [(ngModel)] its create field name same on runtime .. please look mentioned picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtwfC.png

Comment: There's no direct correlation between the field name and your form-model. Assuming you have an array of headerFields as suggessted above, you should be able to set  [(ngModel)]="headerField[i].url" and likewise for type.

If that isnt the answer youre looking for, can you elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have accordions that are generated from configFields by loop. Each accordions have form and fields. if i try to insert data in 1st accordion that are also inserted in 2nd accordion  ... like example you can look in picture i.stack.imgur.com/EtwfC.png accordion's form data are going to insert in headerFields Array. by each unique key..

Comment: The reason why changing one accordion's data is reflecting in another accordion is because you are binding all URL inputs to one single model (i.e. headerFields.url). Similarly, all method inputs are bound to the same model (i.e. headerFields.method). The snippet I shared above will be creating an array of headerFields models so that each accordion can get mapped to its own unique headerField model. Can you elaborate more if the problem isn't what we are comprehending?

Answer (score 0):

How about using form array instead?

file component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {


form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      config: fb.array([])
    });
  }

  addNewAddressGroup() {
    const add = this.form.get('config') as FormArray;
    add.push(
      this.fb.group({
        url: [],
        type: []
      })
    );
  }

  deleteAddressGroup(index: number) {
    const add = this.form.get('config') as FormArray;
    add.removeAt(index);
  }
}
```

file html.ts

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div>
    <button (click)="addNewAddressGroup()">Add</button>
  </div>

  <div
    *ngFor="let addressGroup of form.get('config').controls;let i = index"
    [formGroup]="addressGroup">
    
    <div>Url <input formControlName="url" /></div>
    <div>Type <input formControlName="type" /></div>
    <button (click)="deleteAddressGroup(i)">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>

result <br />

<pre>
{{form.value | json}}
</pre>
```

You can check out this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-exa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29306431)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I edited my answer